# react-scripts + @ckeditor5, latest stable versions incompatibility

Tags: webpack, ckeditor, react-scripts, craco

I've been using a combination of react-scripts + craco to build a project using @ckeditor, but unfortunately it seems that with recent updates to some dependencies I am no longer able to build the project (for the past month or so).

So, when I run `npm run build` - which is basically `craco build` (but it is the same when trying `react-scripts build`) I get the following error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

Adding in a console log to the build.js file of react-scripts I can find the cause to be:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
at MiniCssExtractPlugin.apply (/xxx/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/index.js:87:42)
at webpack (/xxx/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:51:13)
at build (/xxx/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:156:20)
at /xxx/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:85:12
```

But of course fixing that doesn't help. There are another 3 or 4 similar issues with "mini-css-extract-plugin" and if I workaround all manually the issue gets moved to another plugin. So this could be endless and not a way to go.

However, it might possibly be related to "mini-css-extract-plugin" which is a dependency for @node_modules/react-scripts.

I've also been able to figure out that if I go from the latest "30.xy.z" version of https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils back to "29.0.2" the app gets build-able again. However, I am 100% positive I was able to use version 30+ before. I even had to update my craco.config.js for this to work due to some major changes and it did.

Anyway, as noted already this doesn't seem to be related to craco considering basic react-scripts return the same error and it is ultimately the react-scripts build.js file that throws that error.

Oh, and when I try running `craco start` I had a feeling it worked just fine but now it doesn't seem to either. Getting a different error though:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSnapshot')
at /xxx/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/webpack5/file-watcher-api.js:13:36
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.createSnapshot (/xxx/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/webpack5/file-watcher-api.js:12:10)
at /xxx/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/cached-child-compiler.js:219:35
```

I suspect this is a long shot but I am afraid I need to ask nonetheless as I am out of ideas. What could cause this kind of behavior? And is there something I can try to test this further that could shed some more light on why this is happening?

As for the code, I tried a minimal non-working example in which I don't even have to use CKEditor or basically nothing but basic React. It is a "Hello World" but having these packages as dependencies seems enough for this not to work. And as noted, simply going from: `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^30.0.0"` to: `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^29.0.0"` does make it work. But I don't feel like sticking with an old version of this package is a good solution long term.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Before I posted this question, I've been able to make things work using development releases of some of the packages.

It looks as though react-scripts seem to requite older webpack than what ckeditor now uses and craco requires react-scripts 4.x. This is overall quite messy.

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11631
- https://github.com/dilanx/craco/issues/426

Not sure if that was the only error present as I only bumped to this in my minimal example and only after a while, but basically moving to development versions of craco (latest) and react-scripts (not latest, but 5.0.x to work with craco) seems to do the trick and this stuff works again:

```
{
  "name": "crctest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^30.0.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0-alpha.7",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 craco start",
    "build": "craco build"
  }
}
```

For the reference, I've been previously relying on:

```
"@craco/craco": "^6.1.2",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
```

and it is still weird that it worked up until recently even with `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils` 30.0.0+ that I can no longer make work now with old react-scripts. And what I suppose is even more sad is the fact this error didn't pop up right away. For that reason I decided to keep my desperate question here and include this no at all ideal but at least some answer as well.